# How can I inform license details to RavenDB throw Docker-Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ravendb

I'm trying to create 3 RavenDB containers using docker.
This is working as expected, but, I need do inform license details to RavenDB and I could not get this working.

this is my first try docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  raven1:
    container_name: raven1
    image: ravendb/ravendb
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 38888:38888
    environment:
      - RAVEN_LICENSE='{"Id":"xxx","Name":"abc","Keys":["111","222","333","444","555","666","777","888","999"]}'
      - RAVEN_Security_UnsecuredAccessAllowed=PublicNetwork
      - RAVEN_Setup_Mode=None
      - RAVEN_License_Eula_Accepted=true
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl=http://0.0.0.0:8080"
      - "RAVEN_PublicServerUrl=http://localhost:8080"
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://0.0.0.0:38888"
      - "RAVEN_PublicServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://localhost:38888"

  raven2:
    container_name: raven2
    image: ravendb/ravendb
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 38889:38888
    environment:
      - RAVEN_LICENSE='{"Id":"xxx","Name":"abc","Keys":["111","222","333","444","555","666","777","888","999"]}'
      - RAVEN_Security_UnsecuredAccessAllowed=PublicNetwork
      - RAVEN_Setup_Mode=None
      - RAVEN_License_Eula_Accepted=true
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl=http://0.0.0.0:8080"
      - "RAVEN_PublicServerUrl=http://localhost:8081"
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://0.0.0.0:38888"
      - "RAVEN_PublicServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://localhost:38889"

  raven3:
    container_name: raven3
    image: ravendb/ravendb
    ports:
      - 8082:8080
      - 38890:38888
    environment:
      - RAVEN_LICENSE='{"Id":"xxx","Name":"abc","Keys":["111","222","333","444","555","666","777","888","999"]}'
      - RAVEN_Security_UnsecuredAccessAllowed=PublicNetwork
      - RAVEN_Setup_Mode=None
      - RAVEN_License_Eula_Accepted=true
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl=http://0.0.0.0:8080"
      - "RAVEN_PublicServerUrl=http://localhost:8082"
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://0.0.0.0:38888"
      - "RAVEN_PublicServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://localhost:38890"
```

I get containers working, but a "no licensed server" message.

My second try was:

```
version: '3'
services:
  raven1:
    container_name: raven1
    image: ravendb/ravendb
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 38888:38888
    environment:
      - RAVEN_Security_UnsecuredAccessAllowed=PublicNetwork
      - RAVEN_Setup_Mode=None
      - RAVEN_License_Eula_Accepted=true
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl=http://0.0.0.0:8080"
      - "RAVEN_PublicServerUrl=http://localhost:8080"
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://0.0.0.0:38888"
      - "RAVEN_PublicServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://localhost:38888"
    env_file: ./license.env

  raven2:
    container_name: raven2
    image: ravendb/ravendb
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 38889:38888
    environment:
      - RAVEN_Security_UnsecuredAccessAllowed=PublicNetwork
      - RAVEN_Setup_Mode=None
      - RAVEN_License_Eula_Accepted=true
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl=http://0.0.0.0:8080"
      - "RAVEN_PublicServerUrl=http://localhost:8081"
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://0.0.0.0:38888"
      - "RAVEN_PublicServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://localhost:38889"
    env_file: ./license.env

  raven3:
    container_name: raven3
    image: ravendb/ravendb
    ports:
      - 8082:8080
      - 38890:38888
    environment:
      - RAVEN_Security_UnsecuredAccessAllowed=PublicNetwork
      - RAVEN_Setup_Mode=None
      - RAVEN_License_Eula_Accepted=true
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl=http://0.0.0.0:8080"
      - "RAVEN_PublicServerUrl=http://localhost:8082"
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://0.0.0.0:38888"
      - "RAVEN_PublicServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://localhost:38890"
    env_file: ./license.env
```

this version points to a license.env file with

```
RAVEN_LICENSE='{"Id":"xxx","Name":"abc","Keys":["111","222","333","444","555","666","777","888","999"]}'
```

inside of it

both versions didnt work.

what am I doing wrong? Whats the correct way to inform the license detais to RavenDB using Docker?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "RAVEN_LICENSE" all caps, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
remove the single quote and all whitespace from "license.env"